# MVC3 HtmlHelper returns &#39;

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html-entities

How can I make a MVC3 Html helper return a string which is not html encoded?

The following method:

```
    public static string SelectedIfEqual(this int id, int otherId)
    {

        if (id == otherId)
            return new MvcHtmlString(" selected='selected'").ToString();
        return null;  

    }
```

returns `selected=&#39;selected&#39;` rather than `selected='selected'`.

I have even tried:

```
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(" selected='selected'").ToHtmlString();
```

but it returns the same... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return an `HtmlString` or pass the result to a `Html.Raw()` call.
Change your function to:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SelectedIfEqual(this int id, int otherId)
{
  if (id == otherId)
    return new MvcHtmlString(" selected='selected'");
  return null;  
}
```

If you don't want to change your code, add an extension to `HtmlHelper`:

```
public static class MyHelper
{
  // This doesn't work
  //public static Foo Grid(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
  //{
  //  return new Foo(id).ToString();
  //}

  // This should work as intended
  public static MvcHtmlString Foo(this HtmlHelper helper, Foo theFoo)
  {
    return theFoo.ToHtmlString();
  }
}
```

In the class `Foo`, the `ToHtmlString()` method will look like

```
public MvcHtmlString ToHtmlString() 
{
  return new MvcHtmlString(ToString());
}
```

And then in the view you may use

```
@Html.Foo(theFoo)
```

If you don't want to use an Extension Helper, you may as well go with:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.idField.SelectIfEqual(otherId))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean: 

return new HtmlString(" selected='selected'").ToString();

Comment: Edited with some real life samples. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could create a helper class that does not encode HTML attributes that are added..

```
public class HtmlAttributeNoEncoding : System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder
{
    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, System.IO.TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(value);
    }
}
```